# Contradictory Oracle query result

Tags: sql, oracle

I perform two queries and get strange result. I'd like to know why is this happening.
Now queries:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b, TABLE_C c
  WHERE a.a = b.a (+)
  AND b.c = c.c
  AND a.a = 123;
```

Result is empty.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b, TABLE_C c
  WHERE a.a = b.a (+)
  AND b.c = c.c
  AND a.a = 123;
```

Result is 1.

It is really the same query with different returned value. 
Table A contains row with 'a' field = 123.
Table B does not contain rows as a.a = b.a.

How can nothing or 1 be returned for the same query?

**Update:**

When I make it this way

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b, TABLE_C c
  WHERE a.a = b.a (+)
  AND b.c = c.c (+)
  AND a.a = 123;
```

It works OK.

Comment: Reform your query using ANSI-92 syntax (`LEFT JOIN`, etc), and then try it.  It's 20 years old, I think it's had time to bed in!

Comment: What about `TABLE_C`? what is in it?

Comment: @Dems. Damn, I wish I could +1 more than once sometimes...

Comment: In SQL Server the old style outer joins are deprecated as can be ambiguous. Maybe the same in Oracle?

Comment: That does not sound like good explanation...

Comment: obviously test tables/data.  Why not show entire script with echo on instead of having us guess: create table A ... insert into A ... select ...

Comment: @arcane - It is a good *possible* explanation.  Your query has `A OUTER JOIN b` but also `b INNER JOIN c`.  The order is important to determine the results: `(a OUTER JOIN b) INNER JOIN c` or `a OUTER JOIN (b INNER JOIN c)`?  The `,` notation is ambiguous.  If you express this using JOIN notation, the ambiguity of the order is removed, and you can predict the results.  It appears that at present the order of operation is different in your two queries, just because the optimiser decided so.

Comment: @arcane - Your edit includes a revision where both joins are outer joins.  In that case the order of the operations isn't important, but the logic is different.  Seriously, try the `JOIN` syntax to avoid the ambiguity introduced by the (+) operator...

Comment: When you say "result is 1", do you mean 1 row, or the actual value "1" in the `COUNT(*)` column?  I'm just trying to make sure there is not some confusion of terminology going on here.

Comment: @Dems: I would add: The `,` and the `(+)`  notations, when combined, are ambiguous.

Comment: No confusion in terminology. Actual result is "1". Thanks to Dems. I suspected the difference in execution plans or some optimisation.

Comment: @Dems. I believe ANSI syntax is rewritten by the optimizer to be the same as the Oracle syntax. The two shouldn't be different.

Comment: @eaolson - No, neither is rewritten to the other.  Both are compiled to plans, which are not in SQL of any kind.  The discrepancy arises because ANSI-92 is not ambiguous about the logic that is being expressed.  As shown in my 2nd comment above, however, the exact query supplied by the OP *is* ambiguous.  Should the INNER join be applied before or after the OUTER?  This ambiguity lead the optimiser to generate two different plans with two different logical behaviors.  In simpler cases he two syntax yield the same plan, in this case the `,` syntax itself can be interpreted in two different ways

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have indices or foreign key constraints that are not consistent with the table data. Since these two queries most likely use different indices, they return inconsistent data.

Have you temporarily disabled the constrataints, or set them up without validating that they have initially been valid (`ENABLE NOVALIDATE`)?

Try to rebuild the indices and drop and recreate the foreign key constraints to see whether that fixes your problem.